# What is the difference of document() and fn:doc() in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

What is the difference between `document()` and `fn:doc()` in XSLT?

Comment: This is easily answerable with an Internet search engine.  Did you look?

Comment: @JimGarrison I did look

Answer (score 6):

The `document` function was introduced [in 1999 in XSLT 1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#document) and has the following signature: `node-set document(object, node-set?)`, that is, it takes an object as the first argument and an optional second argument of type node-set and returns a node-set. The first argument can be a node-set of URI values, e.g. given the input `<files><file>doc1.xml</file><file>doc2.xml</file><file>doc3.xml</file></files>` a call of `document(/files/file)` returns a union of three document nodes `document('file1.xml') | document('file2.xml') | document('file3.xml')`.

The further development of XSLT and XPath 2.0 joined forces with the XQuery 1.0 development and defined [common functions for XSLT and XPath 2.0 and XQuery 1.0 in 2007](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/), one of them is [the `doc` function](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-doc) which has the following signature: `fn:doc($uri as xs:string?) as document-node()?`, that is the function takes a single string argument with a URI and returns a document node (or it takes an empty sequence as its argument and returns an empty sequence), so basically it loads a single XML document with e.g. `doc('file1.xml')`.

The `document` function continues to [be available in XSLT 2.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#document) and there has the signatures

```
document($uri-sequence as item()*) as node()*
document($uri-sequence as item()*, $base-node as node()) as node()*
```

As you can see in the linked spec, the `doc` function is used to explain the semantics of the `document` function in XSLT 2.0.

Additionally, the `document` function allows the use of fragment identifiers in the URI reference arguments.

In summary, the `doc` function allows the parsing of a single document in XSLT and XPath 2.0 and later and in XQuery 1.0 and later while the `document` function is more complex and its use is restricted to XSLT.